# How do I display offsite database info on my wordpress site?

Tags: php, multisite, database, mysql, migration

I host some online games from my personal computer which the game saves information to my Mysql database. I would like to display live data (if possible) on my hosted Wordpress site. I know the easiest way would to do a remote connection, but my host does not allow that. All I am trying to do is pull some data from a table (character health, humanity level, etc) and have it displayed on a page.

I would appreciate any possible answers. Is there any possibility to display this info another way on my computer and pull it from my Wordpress site not using the remote database method?

I do not know much about this topic so please explain any answers or give me topics I can Google.

Comment: If you can't make a database connection from your site to the game server then you will have to make some other kind of request-- perhaps build some kind of API on the game server so you can request data over HTTP. But nothing I see here is WordPress specific.

Comment: Might want to look into getting a new host too, no remote connections is kind of silly.

Answer (score 2):

As @s_ha_dum mentioned in the comments, building an API or some sort of XML or JSON feed (or leveraging one that's already there, or installing a plugin on whatever system that is, etc) is really your only way of getting at that data remotely. Once you get that going, you can use [wp_remote_get](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get) to query the API.

To make this question a little more WordPress specific, let's say you made a JSON feed at domain.com/games.json. In order to get it from within WordPress, you might do something like this:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://domain.com/games.json' );
if ( !is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $data = json_decode( $response->body ) );
    # Do something with $data
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate that response Matthew. Like I said, I am not very familiar with this stuff so I will definitely look into this JSON feed stuff, that sounds very much what I am looking for. Thank you, I'll give it a try

Comment: Happy to help and best of luck!